# Firebase Phone Authentication issue on Safari, Iphone

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an angular 5 site that uses Firebase Phone Authentication. It has been tested on browsers - Chrome, Edge, Firefox. However, I have been seeing a peculiar issue with Safari on iPhone (Tested with iPhone 7). When I load the website, I see the following request being sent, and multiple of these are being sent. These requests are then returning 404 page (from the server side rendered angular app). I don't see these requests when I test with Chrome / Firefox etc. I have added our domain to Firebase authorized domains. I am using NPM package [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) v4.5. Has anyone encountered such a problem? Please help!

```
/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=<my api  key>&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=4.6.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m;%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_US.8cRDzGyX0Jg.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DIA%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOumnctmUFyV5XKENARAyGn9omQBg#id=I0_1518510096392&_gfid=I0_1518510096392&parent=https%253A%252F%252F<domain>&pfname=&rpctoken=27250867
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth uses an IFrame to run some trusted code during user login.  It essentially verifies that the request is legitimate (and is related to the reCAPTCHA verifier). You can take a look at the code that creates it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/263596a6aeb059acf19a619b00716b9a0ae624c4/packages/auth/src/iframeclient/ifchandler.js#L80)

Unfortunately IFrame support isn't great in Safari - there are a bunch of limitations around local storage and iframe to main window communication.  It sounds like Angular Universal may be causing this to break.

You could try using the Angular Firebase Library [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/1377). They've been working on support of ssr. If it doesn't work then they can help debug.

Otherwise, try updating to the latest firebase npm package, and file a bug against the [firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the firebase sandbox environment. Issue is reproducible there as well (while accessing the sandbox url in safari on an iPhone). So it does not seem to be Angular / Universal problem. For now, I have raised a bug against firebase-js-sdk https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/512